# Find function not working when migration mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to write a migration in mongodb
I have up function

```
async up(db, client) {
        const posts = await db.collection('post').find();
        console.log(posts);
....
    },
```

But when log posts output as:

```
FindCursor {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(topology)]: Topology {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      topologyDescriptionChanged: [Array],
      connectionPoolCreated: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionPoolClosed: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCreated: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionReady: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionClosed: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckOutStarted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckOutFailed: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckedOut: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckedIn: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionPoolCleared: [Function (anonymous)],
      commandStarted: [Function (anonymous)
```

I try findOne, it's well working
I don't know Find() is not working, please help me

Comment: are you using any npm for Mongodb  like mongodb,mongoose?
Could you, please, elaborate more on query?

Comment: @PramodKharade I want to get all records in the post collection, I try findOne() it well works, but when I try to find() so not working, I use migrate-mongo package

Comment: Could you please, show your complete file code where I want to see your import npm libraries

Comment: I have fix by add .toArray()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to fix your code as followed:

```
async up(db, client) {
        const posts = await db.collection('post').find({}).toArray();
        console.log(posts);
....
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

const posts = await db.collection('post').find().toArray()